# Configure SMTP in Windows Server 2012 to send emails using another SMTP configured Windows server(Locally connected)

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, smtp

I have already configured an smtp in **windows server 2012(*call it as X*)** and can send emails using my web application successfully. But I have an other **windows server2012(*call it as Y*)** there I am trying to configure smtp but Internet connection is disabled for security purpose.

I need to forward all smtp request from **Y** to **X** so that **X** can able to send emails.

Answer (score 1):

You need SMTP relay service on server? that able to send emails.

I don't know what Windows Server version you use, but  there [detailed instruction how configure SMTP relay on 2012 server](http://www.vsysad.com/2014/09/setup-and-configure-smtp-server-on-windows-server-2012/))